# Execute azure site swap as part of a kudu deploy

Tags: azure, kudu, azure-cli

I would like to build my deployment so that at the end of the deploy it swaps the new site into production. I'm using deployment slots so the command `azure site swap mysite` shoud do what im after

To do this I tried this in my kudu deploy script eg:

```
echo Swapping into prod
call :ExecuteCmd azure site swap mysite
IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
```

But it appears the azure CLI isn't installed in kudu.

> 'azure' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file. Swapping into prod

Is there a way I can do this inside my deploy script?

Comment: I don't know much about deploy scripts, but have you tried the `Switch-AzureWebsiteSlot` PowerShell cmdlet?

Comment: @benv unfortunatly it has the same problem 'The term 'switch-azurewebsiteslot' is not recognized 
as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program'

Comment: What is the reason for switching sites as part of the deployment?  Why not just deploy straight to the given slot?

Comment: @brendangreen I am deploying to staging running a ui test suite and then if it passes swapping into prod but there are several reasons to want to swap as part of deploy, eg app warm-up before switching it live

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install the azure-cli as part of the build via NPM.

Eg,

```
call :ExecuteCmd npm install azure-cli
call :ExecuteCmd azure login /*some deets*/
call :ExecuteCmd azure site swap mysite
```

However its kinda dumb you have to login to azure to do this. It would be far better if there were a way to re-use the current credentials of the deploy to do the switch. If someone posts such an answer I will accept that.